# I have a error in my Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am having issues with my code and internet explorer is telling me that I have an Object required error on this line of my code:

```
document.getElementById(xDiv).style.display='none'
```

Comment: is xDiv a variable in your js holding some value ? add more of your code so that we can figure out

Comment: We're going to need to see more code than that.

Comment: You are missing the quotes. document.getElementById("xDiv").style.display='none'

Comment: Looks like you're missing either `xDiv` itself or the DOM node that it's supposed to be the id of....

Comment: I don't see an actual question mark in here, what is the actual error and please change your title to something more descripting 'I have error' tells us exactly nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written, "xDiv" represents a javascript variable whose value should be the id of an element in your DOM. If the value of xDiv is not the id of an element in your DOM, then document.getElementById(xDiv) will not resolve to an object. In this case, you will not be able to access the style property, which is giving you this exception.

Replace your line of code with

```
alert(document.getElementById(xDiv));
```

It'll probably alert something like undefined or null.